Multivariate polynomial approximation of functions in Sobolev space
I found a result of the estimation error of polynomial approximation in page
6 of https://scg.ece.ucsb.edu/publications/theses/ARajagopal_2019_Thesis.pdf
The statement is for $f \in W^{k, p}\left([-1,1]^q\right)$ and $n \geq 1$, there exists a constant $C=$ $C(k, p)$ and a polynomial $p_n$ of degree not exceeding $n$ such that
$$
\left\|f-p_n\right\|_{L^p} \leq C\|f\|_{W^{k, p}} n^{-k} .
$$
I think it is a simplifed version of multivariate Jackson's inequality, but I failed to find a reference of this result. Does anyone know the reference? Thanks.

You can find this in 'Weakly Differentiable
Functions' by Ziemer, Corollary 4.2.3, page 184. In this corollary, $k$ is the degree of the approximating polynomial and $0\le k < m$, ($m$ is what you have called $k$). Please note that the statement of the corollary contains a minor typo: the norm on the right-hand-side should be $||D^{k+1}u||_{m-(k+1),p;\Omega}$

Thanks for your reply! Could you please explain more about how to transform the corollary to the statement above? In the corollary, k is the smoothness but here k is the order. Maybe I missed something. Thanks

I really appreciate your help. But I still failed to derive it. (i) After taking $k=m-1$, the right hand side becomes $C(\frac{|T|}{T(1)})^m |D^m u|{p,\Omega}$, what is the expression of $T$? And how to get the $n^{-m}$ term? (ii) Since $p^*>p$, we have $|\cdot|{p^*}<|\cdot|_{p}$, then how to derive the left hand side? (iii) Does the result allow $p=\infty$? Sorry I am not quite familar with the functional analysis, could you please explain more?

Auctually I am stuck in how to choose $T$. Also, I think if $p\leq r$, then $|\cdot|_p\geq |\cdot|_r$

$T$ is a functional you can choose, for example choose $T(f):=\int_\Omega f$, and $p=\infty$ is allowed. The correct inequality really is $|\cdot|{p} \le K |\cdot|{p^*}$ where the constant $K>0$ depends on the measure of the domain.
